# One culprit folder is changing the "ThisPc" view settings

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

Windows 10 pro. All folders are saving its views that I set for them. For example, "ThisPc" is set to "Tiles" and "Group by Type." Most other folders are in the "general" type and are set to "list," sort by name and no grouping.

I have a FEW that have minor changes.
For example, my downloads folder is set to list and "sort by date modified" (so I see newly downloaded files first.) My "Screenshots" folder is also set to "sort by date modified" but is set to "large icon view" (so I see the image of the last taken screenshot first)

There is ONE folder however, called "PROGS," which I want to be like most of the other folder... Type:"general" View:"list" Sort:"by name" Group:"none"

Sounds simple enough. Problem is, when I installed Windows, that "PROGS" folder opened like the "ThisPc"... View:"Tiles" Group:"by type"

Whatever I change the PROGS folder to - the "ThisPC" changes to that as well. And whatever I change the "ThisPC" to - the PROGS folder changes to that as well.

The PROGS folder is set to "general."

I have already deleted the BAGS in the registry, and reset registry values, which takes it all back to when I installed Windows but when I change the PROGS folder's view, the same issue happens.

This is the registry script I run to reset.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What is the full path of PROGS? Try to transfer all files of PROGS to a new folder, delete PROGS, then rename the folder to PROGS.

Comment: The full path is: "H:\PROGS" Your solution didn't work, BUT if I change the folder name to something like "0 PROGS" then it doesn't make the issue. As soon as I change it back to PROGS - the same problem happens again. I need the name to be PROGS. Even more strange... when I change the folder name to anything else, it goes back to list view and no group - automatically. As soon as I put back the name PROGS, the view changes to tiles and it's grouped by type.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the folder's Properties, General tab. Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Here is the screenshot https://imagez.to/i/J6YlCPAl.jpg (as you know, the "read-only" checkmark is meaningless here and is not really in the folder attributes). I did not try in safe-mode.

Comment: What is the nature of disk H? Is it a network share?

Comment: Regular internal 500GB SATA drive. Not connected to network. https://imagez.to/i/RoOkspGW.jpg

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem - there is nothing special about a folder called `PROGS`. I suggest again testing in [Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode), to see if it's some installed third-party program which is the cause of this weird side-effect.

Comment: Tried in safe mode. Same issue. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although deleting ALL Bags in the registry and starting fresh didn't solve the issue, I tried something that DID work. I did a search for the folder name in the registry (PROGS) and marked "Match case" and from the results, I deleted all the bag entries:

[image]

Have no idea what the link was between the "This PC" bags and the PROGS folder bags but the problem is solved!!! Hope this helps someone one day.